# Correctly reusing storage of a union member and casting the involved pointers (object pool)

Tags: c++, unions, lifetime, c++20, object-model

I'm trying to write a C++20 standard conforming object pool that relies on the new wording around the object model that eliminates some undefined behaviour. The comments show the paragraph of the standard draft that I used for my reasoning (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861).

On creation the pool allocates storage for a fixed number of objects and manages a freelist inside the unused storage. For now I assume that the type `T` has no const or reference non-static members.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class ObjectPool {
public:
    using value_type = T;

    ObjectPool(std::ptrdiff_t capacity) :
        m_capacity(capacity),
        m_nodes(
            // Cast the result pointer back to Node* (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.static.cast#13)
            static_cast<Node*>(
                /*
                Implicitly creates (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.memobj#intro.object-10 and https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.memobj#intro.object-13):
                    * the Node[capacity] array
                    * the Node union objects
                    * the Node* member subobjects

                Returns a pointer to the array casted to void* (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.memobj#intro.object-11)
                */
                operator new(capacity * sizeof(Node))
            )
        )
    {
        /*
        The implicit creations happen because it makes the following code defined behaviour.
        Otherwise it would be UB because:
            * Pointer arithmetic without them pointing to elements of an Node[capacity] array (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.add#4)
            * Accessing Node objects through 'pointer to object' pointers outside their lifetime (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.life#6.2).
            * Accessing the Node* subobjects through 'pointer to object' pointers outside their lifetime.
        */

        // Add all nodes to the freelist.
        Node* next = nullptr;
        for (std::ptrdiff_t i = m_capacity - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            m_nodes[i].next = next;
            next = &m_nodes[i];
        }
        m_root = next;
    }

    ~ObjectPool()
    {
        /*
        Release the allocated storage.
        This ends the lifetime of all objects (array, Node, Node*, T) (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.life#1.5).
        */
        operator delete(m_nodes);
    }

    template <typename... Args>
    T* create(Args&&... args)
    {
        // freelist is empty
        if (!m_root) throw std::bad_alloc();

        Node* new_root = m_root->next;

        /*
        Activate the 'storage' member (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.union#7).
        Is this strictly necessary?
        */
        new(&m_root->storage) Storage;

        /*
        Create a T object in the storage of the std::aligned_storage object (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.memobj#intro.object-1).

        This ends the lifetime of the std::aligned_storage object (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.life#1.5)?
        Because std::aligned_storage is most likley implemented with a unsigned char[N] array (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/meta.trans.other#1),
        it 'provides storage' (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.object#3)
        for the T object and so the T object is 'nested within' (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.object#4.2) the std::aligned_storage
        which does not end its lifetime.
        This means without knowing the implementation of std::aligned_storage I don't know if the lifetime has ended or not?

        The union object is still in it's lifetime? The T object is 'nested within' the union object because it is
        'nested within' the member subobject 'storage' because that 'provides storage' (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.object#4.3).

        The union has no active members (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.union#2).
        */
        T* obj = new(&m_root->storage) T{std::forward<Args>(args)...};

        m_root = new_root;
        return obj;
    }

    void destroy(T* obj)
    {
        /* Destroy the T object, ending it's lifetime (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.life#5). */
        obj->~T();

        /* if std::aligned_storage is in its lifetime.

        T represents the first byte of storage and is usable in limited ways (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.life#6).
        The storage pointer points to the std::aligned_storage object (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.reinterpret.cast#7 and https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.static.cast#13).

        I'm not sure is std::launder() is necessary here because we did not create a new object.

        Storage* storage = reinterpret_cast<Node*>(storage);
        */

        /* if std::aligned_storage is not in its lifetime.

        Create a std::aligned_storage object in the storage of the former T object (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.memobj#intro.object-1).

        This activates the 'storage' member of the corresponding union (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.union#2).
        */
        Storage* storage = new(obj) Storage;

        /*
        Get a pointer to the union from a pointer to a member (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.compound#4.2).
        */
        Node* node = reinterpret_cast<Node*>(storage);

        /*
        Activate the 'next' member creating the corresponding subobject (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.union#6),
        the lifetime of the 'storage' subobject ends.
        */
        node->next = m_root;
        m_root = node;
    }

    std::ptrdiff_t capacity() const
    {
        return m_capacity;
    }
private:
    using Storage = typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type;

    union Node {
        Node* next;
        Storage storage;
    };
    std::ptrdiff_t m_capacity;
    Node* m_nodes;
    Node* m_root;
};

struct Block {
    long a;
    std::string b;
};

int main(int, char **)
{
    ObjectPool<Block> pool(10);

    Block* ptrs[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        ptrs[i] = pool.create(i, std::to_string(i*17));
    }
    std::cout << "Destroying objects\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::cout << ptrs[i]->a << " " << ptrs[i]->b << "\n";
        pool.destroy(ptrs[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My biggest problem is to understand what I have to do to transform the `T*` pointer in the `destroy(T*)` function into a `Node*` pointer to a usable `Node` object so can can add it to the freelist?

What I also don't understand how objects and subobjects work if they use the exact same storage area (union and their members) and I reuse the storage of a member. The subobjects (member) lifetime ends but does the parent object (union) stay in its lifetime despite all of its storage is reused?

Comment: It's not clear why you need `Node` to be a union at all. Why can't it just be a pointer to the next element? What is the purpose of `storage` in the `union`?

Comment: `Node` must be aligned and big enough to hold a `T`. Thats what the `std::aligned_storage` provides. I could use `std::aligned_storage` alone but then the fact that sometimes there are `Node*` in there is hidden in the `create()` and `destroy()` functions. Maybe it's better to use a `T` object as a member and define a default constructor that initialises the `next` pointer? In the end I'm trying to figure out whats the best way to implement it in a standard conforming way.

Comment: "*`Node` must be aligned and big enough to hold a `T`.*" ... why? Can't you just placement-`new` the `T` on top of the pointer?

Answer (score 2):

The way you're going about this is unnecessarily overdesigned. It can still work, but the specific changes you're talking about with regard to implicit object creation (IOC) are unrelated to your code, for the most part. Or rather, you can do what you're attempting without relying on IOC (and thus write code that functions under C++17).

So let's start from the beginning: your memory allocation.

You allocate a bunch of memory. But your goal is to allocate an array of `Node`s. So... *just do that*. Just invoke `new Node[capacity]` instead of allocating unformed memory. There's no point in relying on IOC to solve a problem you can *trivially* solve yourself (and it can be argued that the result is much more readable as to what is going on).

So, after allocating the array, you put a bunch of values into it. You do this by using the `next` member of the `Node` union. This works because the first member of a `union` is always active upon creation (unless you do something special). So all `Node` objects have the `next` member active.

Now, let's move on to the creation of `T`. You want to activate `Node::storage`. Placement `new` works in this case, but you'll still need it even with IOC. That is, IOC does not change the rules of `union`s. A union member can only [implicitly be activated by an assignment to the named member](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.union#6). And you're not trying to do that; you're only going to use its address. So you still need the placement-`new` call to activate the member.

You then use placement-`new` to create the `T` itself within `storage`. And now we get to talk about lifetime.

You cite [[basic.life]/1.5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.life#1.5) to suggest that once you do this, `storage`'s lifetime ends. This is true, but it's only because you used `aligned_storage_t`.

Let's pretend that, instead of `std::aligned_storage_t`, you had used `alignas(T) unsigned char[sizeof(T)]` for the type of `storage`. That matters because byte arrays have special behavior.

If `storage` is so defined, then `T` is *nested within* `storage`. From [[intro.object]/4.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.object#4), we see:

> An object *a* is *nested within* another object *b* if:
>
> ...
>
> - *b* provides storage for *a*, or
>
> ...

And from the previous paragraph, we learn:

> If a complete object is created ([expr.new]) in storage associated with another object e of type “array of N unsigned char” or of type “array of N std​::​byte” ([cstddef.syn]), that array provides storage for the created object if:
>
> - the lifetime of e has begun and not ended, and
> - the storage for the new object fits entirely within e, and
> - there is no smaller array object that satisfies these constraints.

And all of those would be true if you use a byte array, so `storage` would continue to exist even after creating a `T` within it.

If this sounds like a good reason to not use `std::aligned_storage`, that's because it is.

And since all of this is valid C++17, if you switch to an aligned byte array, you don't have to worry; `storage` will continue to be within its lifetime.

Now we come to deletion. Destroying the `T` is the first thing you need to do.

So you've got a pointer to the (just destroyed) object, but you need to get a pointer to the `Node`. That's a problem because... well, you don't have one. I mean, yes, the address of the `T` is the same address as that of `storage`, which is pointer-interconvertible with a pointer to the `Node`. But it's that first step in that process, from pointer-to-`T` to pointer-to-`storage` that's the problem; `reinterpret_cast` can't get you there.

But `std::launder` can. And you can go straight from the `T*` to the `Node*`, because both objects have the same address and the `Node` is within its lifetime.

Once you have a `Node*`, you can reactivate the `next` member of that object. And since you can do it by assignment, there's no need for placement-`new`. So most of the stuff in that function is unnecessary.

And yet again, this is perfectly valid for C++17. Even the [implicit activation of a union member is standard C++17](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.union#5) (with slightly different rules, but the differences don't apply here).

---

So let's look at a valid, C++17 version of your code:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <new>


template <typename T>
class ObjectPool {
public:
    using value_type = T;

    ObjectPool(std::ptrdiff_t capacity)
        : capacity_(capacity)
        , nodes_(new Node[capacity])
    {
        // Add all nodes to the freelist.
        Node* next = nullptr;
        for (std::ptrdiff_t i = capacity_ - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            nodes_[i].next = next;
            next = &nodes_[i];
        }
        root_ = next;
    }

    ~ObjectPool()
    {
        delete[] nodes_;
    }

    template <typename... Args>
    T* create(Args&&... args)
    {
        // freelist is empty
        if (!root_) throw std::bad_alloc();

        auto *allocate = root_;
        root_ = root_->next;

        new(&allocate->storage) decltype(allocate->storage);

        //Note: not exception-safe.
        T* obj = new(&allocate->storage) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        return obj;
    }

    void destroy(T* obj)
    {
        obj->~T();
        
        Node *free = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<Node*>(obj));
        
        free->next = root_;
        root_ = free;
    }

    std::ptrdiff_t capacity() const
    {
        return capacity_;
    }
    
private:
    union Node
    {
        Node* next;
        alignas(T) std::byte storage[sizeof(T)];
    };
    
    std::ptrdiff_t capacity_;
    Node* nodes_;
    Node* root_ = nullptr;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I knew I propably did unnecassary stuff, sometimes one gets lost in the standard.

Comment: Out of curiosity, would `std::launder` still work if I used the `std::aligned_storage`? Its lifetime would end but the `T*` still points to the same address as the `Node` and the node is within its lifetime.